# Send and receive Model with JSON [MVC] [C#]

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to create some view with filters and data table that will by filtered.
The problem is with the filters because they are created dynamically.

```cs
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Test()
    {
        DisplayModel model = new DisplayModel();
        model.Filters = new List<TestFilter>() { new TestFilter() { Name = "Name 1" }, new TestFilter() { Name = "Name 2" }, new TestFilter() { Name = "Name 3" } };
        return View(model);
    }
    public ActionResult JsonChange(List<TestFilter> filters)
    {
        if (filters == null || filters.Count == 0) return PartialView("_Selected", null);
        SelectedModel model = new SelectedModel();
        model.SelectedValues = "";
        foreach (var el in filters)
        {
            model.SelectedValues += (el.Name + " " + el.Value + "<br />");
        }

        return PartialView("_Selected", model);
    }

}
```

Here are my main View

```html
@model TestReport.Models.DisplayModel
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(".submit").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Test/JsonChange/',
            data: '<what should be here>',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#content").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
@foreach (var el in Model.Filters)
{
<div>
    <span>@el.Name</span><span>@Html.TextBoxFor(t => el.Value, null)</span>
</div>
}
<div class="submit" style="border:1px solid black;width:100px;">
Send</div>
```

and here is my partial view that will be changed by ajax calls:

```html
@model TestReport.Models.SelectedModel
You have selected:
<br />
@if (Model != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.SelectedValues))
{
    <text>@Model.SelectedValues</text>
}
```

finally there are my Model

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestReport.Models
{
    public class SelectedModel
    {
        public string SelectedValues { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and Filter class

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace TestReport.Entities
{
    public class TestFilter
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to simplify whole solution to present you my problem.
What i want to accomplish is to Send to controller method all the values of dynamically created input boxes with ajax as object (List).
I know one of the approach is to use $.ajax({}) method. But maybe it`s not the best solution?

Answer (score 0):

here is a post that probably explains about your scenario

http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Comment: Ok. It explain one part of the problem. It would be simple by using @Html.BeginForm() to post such List of objects. But how to accomplish it with ajax?